# AccessDeniedException while creating AWS Web Cloudfront Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS and trying to create a Web CloudFront distribution.

I chose:

- Origin media: wp.s3.s3.amazonaws.com
- Restrict Bucket Access: Yes
- Origin Access Identity: Create a new identity
- Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: Yes, Update Bucket Policy

I get the following error when I click on Create Distribution:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.AccessDeniedException: Your account must be verified before you can add new CloudFront resources. 
To verify your account, please contact AWS Support (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/) and include this error message. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 0ade44b6-42ea-11e9-bd99-45671299fde3)
```

Comment: The error message gives you specific instructions on what to do about the error, so it is not clear what you are asking.  *To verify your account, please contact AWS Support (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/) and include this error message. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 0ade44b6-42ea-11e9-bd99-45671299fde3)*

Comment: If you are *very* new -- that is, if you created the account within the past few hours -- then you may alternately want to wait and simply try again over the next few hours.  AWS is a massive, globally-distributed collection of systems, and anecdotal reports suggest that it can sometimes take a few hours after account creation before all services are activated.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I have been using this AWS account for over 3 months. Since am in a Basic plan I can't contact AWS for technical support. Also, I have been trying to search with the above error message, I couldn't find any related info in any other forums / internet.

Comment: Yes, you can contact support.  For the type of support request, choose "Account and Billing Support" > "Account" > "Other Account Issues" and explain that your account does not allow access to CloudFront, including that message.  *Technical support* is not free, but support for an *account that is not working properly* is not "tech support" and does not require payment.

Comment: @Sai Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: Well...I got stuck in the same problem. I have a free account and want to deploy a PWA app. I successfuly uploaded my distribution files to S3 and I am trying to link it to CloudFront because PWA apps need HTTP access method (S3 only gives HTTP access). I get the error message of this thread when I try to create my CloudFront distribution...

I created a support report but got no reply until now (2 days passed).

Answer (score 7):

A [2014 post](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/about-aws/whats-new/2014/05/08/aws-free-usage-tier-now-includes-amazon-cloudfront/) says that CloudFront is available for the free account.

I tried to create a distribution and got the same message reported in this thread.

I created an issue as "Michael - sqlbot" suggested in the comments above and I receive a reply informing that the service would be enabled for me.

Why do They not create a submission for the distribution creation that make it clear that need a activation from the support team instead of an error message? :S

So it looks like every new free account must follow this steps:

1. Try to create a distribution
2. It will return a error message
3. Create an issue at [support center](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=sa-east-1)
4. Wait for the contact to get the service available

Answer (score 4):

here's how to solve it:

1) Navigate to:
Support / New case / Service limit increase

2) Limit type:
CloudFront Distributions

3) In Requests select:
Limit: Web Distributions per Account
New limit value: 
MY CASE:

In my case, I had 2 distributions, wanted to create 3rd, but coudn't.
So I have put as  a number 10.

**It takes an hour or more to resolve. Be patient**

Answer (score 1):

For me is fixed now:

1. I was able to create CloudFront distribution 2 weeks ago.
2. Week ago CF got broken. I created ticket to support.
3. Were ping-ponging with AWS support for 7 days (they said that it was their fault).
4. I am able to create
   cloud distribution now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to contact AWS Support. They will give some sort to score to your account and if you the score of your account is low, it doesn't allow you to create a CF Distribution. The support will increase that score for you and you should be able to create it after that,

Comment: Do you have any more information about this score? Some links maybe? I feel I experience exactly this situation.